# What's the difference between the .war and .zip file formats?

Tags: zip

I've heard that they are the same, but I would like to know if the compression is always the same.  Can I always rename .zip files to .war, and vice-versa?

Comment: [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KDE_WAR_%28file_format%29) or [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_file_format_%28Sun%29)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you mean [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_file_format_%28Sun%29), then, according to the wiki page, the .war format is the same as the .jar format.  .jar files are just .zip files which contain compiled java code, meant to be used as a library or executable.  So the answer would be **no**, there is no technical difference; but .jar files should only be used for what they're intended for, not as general-purpose archives.

If you mean [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KDE_WAR_%28file_format%29), then there is a slight difference:  this .war format is a gzipped-tar (.tar.gz) file, again meant to hold specific data (web pages).  Gzip and Zip both use the same compression algorithm; [however](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip#File_format):

> Gzip is not to be confused with the ZIP archive format, which also uses [the DEFLATE compression algorithm]. The ZIP format can hold collections of files without an external archiver, but is less compact than compressed tarballs holding the same data, because it compresses files individually and cannot take advantage of redundancy between files.

In both cases, you should only use the .war extension for the specific purpose it's intended for.

Answer (score 5):

ZIP files can contain any kind of file and folder structure.

WAR files (Java Web Application Archives) are based on ZIP, but have a defined folder structure and requirements to some of the files in there (e.g., some stuff needs to be in a `WEB-INF` directory).

So yes, you can rename a .war file to .zip to view its contents or unzip it using a tool that doesn't know about this relationship between the file format. But not just any .zip file will make a working web application — you'll have to be careful in creating the file and folder structure you're bundling up.

Comment: @Randolf Please refrain from editing any of my posts in the future. Thank you.

Comment: @Daniel Beck:  Sorry, did I do something wrong?

Comment: @Randolf It's a discouraged edit as per the `/reputation` explanation for the edit privilege (changing a single character) and really a matter of personal style whether to use or not use the comma after *e.g.* (at least from what I've gathered). I'd actually welcome edits that substantially and objectively improve my posts, but have never even had a single one of those, so I'm kind of wary of them. Plus I'm kind of proud of the low number of edits even though I'm not a native speaker ;)

Comment: @Randolf I don't think you can somehow see them listed (as they're in the *Responses* tab), so FYI: [1](http://superuser.com/posts/190422/revisions), [2](http://superuser.com/posts/200042/revisions), [3](http://superuser.com/posts/228728/revisions), [4](http://superuser.com/posts/243463/revisions), [5](http://superuser.com/posts/203144/revisions), and this one.

Comment: @Daniel Beck:  Normally my edits are fixing major things.  This was one exception where I corrected a minor error.  I had no idea it was causing problems with reputation, and my intentions are to maintain the high quality of content.  I'll try to remember not to edit your posts, but I also don't want to find myself in a "walking on eggshells" situation having to remember who's posts not to edit, so please forgive me in advance if I do forget (this web site doesn't seem to provide any system for add custom notes next to users, otherwise I could add such a note).

Comment: @Daniel Beck:  Perhaps this system needs two buttons with the "Save This Edit" options -- one that effects reputation, and one that doesn't.

Comment: @Randolf I appreciate the work frequent editors do on this site, and am no stranger to the edit button myself. As I wrote, I'm just a bit unlucky with the edits I receive, as they're far from substantial, and I guess that shone through in my first comment, for which I apologize. Also, edits don't remove reputation, I meant to write `/privileges`.

Comment: @Daniel Beck:  Do you know if there's a way I can set my account not to effect other accounts when I make edits?  I'd like to shut that off for all my edits actually, because I believe that what people are trying to convey is a lot more important than how they convey it, yet at the same time I'd like to see the best of both of these worlds here as much as possible.

Comment: @Randolf What do you mean by that? What effect on other accounts? It's displayed as *response* in my profile, just like comments, but that's it.

Comment: @Daniel Beck:  I was responding to your reference of "effecting reputation" before, which you clarified as "privileges."  I'm still quite new to this system, so I don't fully understand how it works.

Comment: @Randolf I meant the http://superuser.com/privileges URL. They explain the different privileges there, and state that edits should be substantial and not single characters. http://superuser.com/reputation also exists, but is just a list of rep changes.

Comment: @Daniel Beck:  Ah, I found what you are referring to (thanks for pointing it out; I remember reading about how edits are encouraged, but I didn't remember about the minor stuff {of course I don't normally edit just one character, so yours was not what I usually do anyway}):  http://superuser.com/privileges/edit

Comment: @Daniel Beck:  As far as reputation goes, you don't need to worry about me because I'm not interested in voting people down (I can't vote anyway yet due to some other problems with getting my account registered), especially as part of an edit (I assume this isn't occurring automatically anyway).

Comment: @Randolf I never assumed you did vote down for something like that — and certainly not for minor grammar issues. Edits don't cause rep changes, as I wrote before. I never did mention reputation, except for the URL I got wrong. Good luck with getting registered, I was kind of surprised to see that you weren't. I hope you made backups of your browser cookies ;-)

Comment: @Daniel, some of those you listed were mine. And actually, I am very tempted to change [4](http://superuser.com/posts/243463/revisions) into using proper quoting rather than abusing code as well...

Comment: (As an aside, @Randolf can always [restore the cookie](http://superuser.com/users/account-recovery) if an email address has been provided earlier.)